# Is there some method to reture one solution of LyapunovSolve even if the solution is not unique?

Tags: differential-equations

I want to find one solution to the Lyapunov equation, and I use `LyapunovSolve[a,c]`. But when the solution is not unique, Mathematica did not return any value instead, it shows

> The matrix equation has no unique solution.

Is there some method that I can get one solution even if the solution is not unique?

**Edit** I try to solve equation
$$\left( \begin{matrix}
    1&      0\\
    0&      -1\\
\end{matrix} \right) =\left( \begin{matrix}
    1+z&        x-iy\\
    x+iy&       1-z\\
\end{matrix} \right) X+X\left( \begin{matrix}
    1+z&        x-iy\\
    x+iy&       1-z\\
\end{matrix} \right)$$

```
    $Assumptions = 
      Element[x, Reals] && Element[y, Reals] && Element[z, Reals];
    Rho =  {
        {1 + z, x - I*y},
        {x + I*y, 1 - z}
       } ;
    c = {
        {1, 0},
        {0, -1}
       } ;
    LyapunovSolve[Rho, c]
```

Comment: Please post your example code.

Comment: `LyapunovSolve[rho, c]` returns a solution for me (V13.1). This has a nicer simplified form: `xmat = LyapunovSolve[rho, c] // ComplexExpand` -- I changed `Rho` to `rho` in accordance with best practices.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think I need to try 13.1. I'm 13.0, so close. :) But is there some better way I can deal now(I will update it later since install a new version is not a quick way)?

Comment: Try it without the `$Assumptions`. (`ComplexExpand` will take care of it after the solution.)

Comment: Here's what I got, if this particular problem is your main interest: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5qxS.png

Comment: @MichaelE2 Still no solution...

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare with `Solve` and `LyapunovSolve`.

```
Clear[rho, c, sol1, sol2];
rho = {{1 + z, x - I*y}, {x + I*y, 1 - z}};
c = {{1, 0}, {0, -1}};
sol1 = {{u, v}, {w, t}} /. 
   Solve[rho . {{u, v}, {w, t}} + {{u, v}, {w, t}} . rho == c, {u, v, 
      w, t}][[1]];
sol2 = LyapunovSolve[rho, c] // ComplexExpand;
sol1 == sol2 // Simplify
```

(* True *)